Does there exist a convolution semigroup with compactly supported density?
I am looking for a convolution semigroup $(P_t)_{t \geq 0}$ of operators acting on $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R^d})$, of the form
$$P_tf(x) = (p_t * f)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} p_t(x-y) f(y) dy,$$
where $p_t$ is compactly supported for each $t \geq 0$.
Does such a family exist? My intuition would be to relate these to diffusion processes, and while I know that there are PDEs with finite speed of propogation, I am unsure whether each one can be related to a convoultion semigroup or how to recover the generator, for example.
